# How can I get all the holders of an LP token for a date range

Tags: solidity, web3js, decentralized-exchange, amm

Is there any api/contract call sample etc that can help me get a list of everyone who holds an LP token within a particular date range? I. E people who held it thro and never transferred it or sold it

I will like to see their balance too

Answer (score 0):

An LP token is a normal ERC-20 token so you can look for normal `Transfer` events or use the `balanceOf` method.

However you would have to set up an Ethereum archive node to do it completely on your own. This is not convenient and I suggest to use a service like Google's Big Query as it offers free credits.

You just have to write the SQL queries to get the information you need, check the Uniswap's [retroactive-query](https://github.com/Uniswap/retroactive-query/) repository for inspiration.